# How to pass `props` to another component in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

I have this component :

```
interface listvote {
  items: any[]
}


const ListVote: React.FC<listvote> = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(items)
  })
  return (
    <VoteResult
      id={props.id}
      img={props.img}
      name={props.name}
      score={props.score}
    />
  )
}

export default ListVote
```

It receives this Array as a prop:

```
<ListVote items={dataListVote} />


const dataListVote = [
    {
      id: 1,
      img:
        'sampleimage.com',
      name: 'samplename',
      score: 50,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      img:
        'sampleimage.com',
      name: 'samplename',
      score: 80,
    },
  ]
```

There is another component inside ListVote :

```
interface voteresult {
  items: any[]
}

const VoteResult: React.FC<voteresult> = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props)
  })
  return <h1>hello</h1>
}

export default VoteResult
```

The problem is when I try to pass the same array to another component inside ListVote component, it throws this error:

```
    Type 'PropsWithChildren<listvote>' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your usage:

```
<VoteResult
      id={props.id}
      img={props.img}
      name={props.name}
      score={props.score}
    />
```

VoteResult *does not accept items* as a prop. So your type is incorrect:

```
interface voteresult {
  items: any[]
}
```

## Correct Type

The simplest type to get rid of the error:

```
interface voteresult {
  id: any;
  img: any;
  name: any;
  score: any;
}
```

Comment: change a question and still getting error see second post

Answer (score 0):

Home component :

```
const dataListVote = [
    {
      id: 1,
      img:
        'sampleimage.com',
      name: 'samplename',
      score: 50,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      img:
        'sampleimage.com',
      name: 'samplename',
      score: 80,
    },
```

]

```
<ListVote items={dataListVote} />
```

ListVote COmponent:

```
interface listvote {
  items: any[]
}

const ListVote: React.FC<listvote> = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(typeof props)
  })
  return <VoteResult items={props} />
}

export default ListVote
```

VoteResult Component :

```
interface listvote {
  items: any[]
}


const VoteResult: React.FC<voteresult> = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props)
  })
  return <h1>hello</h1>
}

export default VoteResult
```

Error :

```
Type 'PropsWithChildren<listvote>' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.
```